# Why does Google Closure Compiler rename object's properties names?

Tags: javascript, json, obfuscation, google-closure-compiler

I'v got an object `obj` from a `JSON.parse`:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(some_data);
```

And it is supposed that `obj` has a property `x`:

```
console.log('Z', obj, obj.x);
```

The console output:

```
Z  Object {x: "m", n: Array[256], t: Array[256], v: Array[256]} undefined
```

As you see, the `obj.x` exists. But the third argument of `console.log` failed to print it because Google Closure Compiler produced the following code:

```
console.log("Z ",a,a.G);
```

The `x` property is renamed to `G`. What is best way to deal with that? The first idea if to use `obj["x"]`.

It is also interesting what is behind the Google Closure Compiler's desigion to rename `x` to `G` for the object that comes from `JSON.parse`, considering that JSON is unavailable to compiler and `x` may exist there?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you understand the [differences in the compilation levels](http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2012/09/which-compilation-level-is-right-for-me.html). Specifically, properties must be referenced consistently.

JSON.parse data results are generally considered external to the compiler (as you noted) - but not always. For instance, you could define your JSON response as an external interface and type cast the results from that call which would allow you to use dotted property access.

In general, property renaming is one of the most powerful features of closure-compiler, and also the most difficult to implement correctly. Your code must be written in a manner that is compatible with `ADVANCED` compilation or it will break.

Answer (score 1):

(not really an answer but this won't fit in a comment).

You need to show an example, or more of your code.  As Chad Killingsworth says if you are applying some type cast or other information to the compiler about your results then Closure Compiler will do renaming.

Here is example code similar to what you showed but it is not doing the renaming.

```
var orig_obj = { x: "m",
n: new Array(256),
t: new Array(256),
v: new Array(256)};
var some_data = JSON.stringify(orig_obj);
var obj = JSON.parse(some_data);
console.log('Z', obj, obj.x);
```

Compiling this with the [online Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520ADD%2520YOUR%2520CODE%2520HERE%250Avar%2520orig_obj%2520%253D%2520%257B%2520x%253A%2520%2522m%2522%252C%250An%253A%2520new%2520Array(256)%252C%250At%253A%2520new%2520Array(256)%252C%250Av%253A%2520new%2520Array(256)%257D%253B%250Avar%2520some_data%2520%253D%2520JSON.stringify(orig_obj)%253B%250Avar%2520obj%2520%253D%2520JSON.parse(some_data)%253B%250Aconsole.log('Z'%252C%2520obj%252C%2520obj.x)%253B%250A) (note that you need to select "advanced" option) results in:

```
a=JSON.stringify({x:"m",n:Array(256),t:Array(256),a:Array(256)}),
b=JSON.parse(a);console.log("Z",b,b.x);
```

Running that code results in the "m" being printed as expected.